# What is the difference between the `ttest` and `ttest2` function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, t-test

I have two samples X and Y, both are N*1 vectors, I found that in Matlab(R2015), both `ttest` and `ttest2` can accept two samples and give the P value, but their results are somewhat different.

For `ttest`, ttest(X,Y) gives P = 1.8e-7, for `ttest2`, ttest2(X,Y) gives P = 8.0e-11. It seems that both functions give relatively low P values. However, I am not familiar with the differences between these two functions, also, if I am going to report the P-value, which value should I choose?

Comment: you should read the help section in matlab: one is a one-sample and the other a two-sample t-test. see [one vs two sample ttest](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/2samplevs1sampletest.html) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more about statistics than programming.

With two samples, `ttest` performs a paired t-test while `ttest2` does a 
genuine two-sample test. The paired test is equivalent to a one-sample t-test 
on the difference of the paired values.